# Simple WAR file merging - overwriting first WAR file with second WAR file

Tags: merge, war, cargo, maven-cargo

I want to simply merge two WAR files, overwriting corresponding files in first WAR with files from second WAR i.e. output WAR will contain web.xml from second WAR if one was present there. I am trying to use cargo-maven2-plugin but I have problems with that. Cargo has some sophisticated mechanism for merging web.xml and in most cases the result is different from that what I need.

I tried some uberwar configurations similar to following ones:

1)

```
<uberwar>
<wars>
    <war>com.xyz:core-module</war>
    <war>com.xyz:core-extension-module</war>
</wars>
<merges>
    <merge>
        <type>web.xml</type>
        <parameters>
            <default>
                <tag name="servlet">
                    <strategy name="Overwrite" />
                </tag>
                <tag name="servlet-mapping">
                    <strategy name="Overwrite" />
                </tag>
            </default>
        </parameters>
    </merge>
</merges>
</uberwar>
```

2)

```
<uberwar>
<wars>
    <war>com.xyz:core-module</war>
    <war>com.xyz:core-extension-module</war>
</wars>
<merges>
    <merge>
        <type>web.xml</type>
        <parameters>
            <default>
                <tag name="servlet">
                    <strategy name="NodeMerge">
                        <servlet>
                            <servlet-name>$left:servlet-name</servlet-name>
                            <servlet-class>$right:servlet-class</servlet-class>
                        </servlet>
                    </strategy>
                </tag>
                <tag name="servlet-mapping">
                    <strategy name="NodeMerge">
                        <servlet-mapping>
                            <servlet-name>$left:param-name</servlet-name>
                            <url-pattern>$right:param-value</url-pattern>
                        </servlet-mapping>
                    </strategy>
                </tag>
            </default>
        </parameters>
    </merge>
</merges>
</uberwar>
```

In both cases I do not get what I want or even something similar to that what I want. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Or maybe Cargo isn't a good tool for that... do you know any other tools that could do same thing and could be integrated with Maven? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the [Maven War Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/index.html). If the [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) order isn't declared the order of the war overlaying appens in the same order  the dependencies are declared.

To get full control of the overlay the **overlays** element should be used.

Comment: I have noticed overlay functionality during topic exploration, but I wasn't sure if that behavior was desired. Thanks to your answer I have investigated more about overlays and now I see that merging functionality is desired. Thanks